# Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads: how to add a bundle to the ad request

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Considering I have an AdView in a Xamarin.Android project:

```
private AdView _bannerAd;
```

I usually initialize it like this:

```cs
_bannerAd = new AdView(this)
{
    AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner,
    AdUnitId = adUnitId,
    Visibility = ViewStates.Visible
};
```

Then, when I load the banner, I have to build the request. In this case I'd like to add an extra bundle, but when I have to call `requestbuilder.AddCustomEventExtrasBundle`, I don't know what to put as the first parameter.

```
var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
var extras = new Bundle();
extras.PutString("npa", "1");
requestbuilder.AddCustomEventExtrasBundle(***, extras);
_bannerAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build())
```

By reading the method definition, I really don't understand what could be an "adapter class".

```
[Register("addCustomEventExtrasBundle", "(Ljava/lang/Class;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;", "")]
public Builder AddCustomEventExtrasBundle(Class adapterClass, Bundle customEventExtras);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the Java Class (via `Java.Lang.Class.FromType`) of your custom event (`ICustomEventBanner`).

In my case, I have one called `SushiHangoverTextEventBanner` that is registered with AdMob.

You need to implement `ICustomEventBanner`, assumably this is a stand alone object (in my case it is) as AdMob will instance it, inherit it from `Java.Lang.Object` so Xamarin will create the ACW (JNI/Java wrapper) for it.

```
public class SushiHangoverTextEventBanner : Java.Lang.Object, ICustomEventBanner
{
    SushiHangoverTextAdView customAdView;

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        customAdView?.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnPause()
    {
        ~~~
    }

    public void OnResume()
    {
        ~~~
    }

    public void RequestBannerAd(Context context, ICustomEventBannerListener listener, string serverParameter, AdSize size, IMediationAdRequest mediationAdRequest, Bundle customEventExtras)
    {
        customAdView = new SushiHangoverTextAdView(context);
        ~~~
    }
}
```

I also have a custom ad (`SushiHangoverAdView` based on a `TextView`) that is used within that `ICustomEventBanner` implementation.

Once you register it and implement the AdMob callbacks, you can just pass it to your `AdRequest.Builder`:

```
using (var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder())
{
    var extras = new Bundle();
    extras.PutString("npa", "1");
    requestbuilder.AddCustomEventExtrasBundle(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SushiHangoverTextEventBanner)), extras);
}
```

I help recommend going through the Admob custom event example:

- https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting a class that extends from `CustomEvent`, per the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#addCustomEventExtrasBundle(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEvent%3E,%20android.os.Bundle))

```
public AdRequest.Builder addCustomEventExtrasBundle (Class<? extends
CustomEvent> adapterClass, Bundle customEventExtras)
```

[Here is a great tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events) on getting started with custom events, directly from Google, where they go over using the `CustomEventBanner`. It is in Java, but should be easy enough to port to C#